# Как суммировать статистические данные?

Tags: php, база-данных, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin, denwer

Я прохожу практику , мне дали задание сделать счетчик статистики (самый простой ) . Я его сделал , теперь попросили сделать так что бы показывали общею сумму "просмотров"  за определенный промежуток времени ( в данном случаи за год ).Уже 4 день сижу и ломаю голову над этим , хоть решение наверное легче легкого но хоть убей не могу додуматься . Помогите пожалуйста. Вот структура таблицы[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Вот код двух главных файлом (на всякий случай)

```html
<?php include '../inc/db.php'; ?>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8" />
<body>
<style>
   body { background-color: #F9F2E3; }
   h2 {
    background-color: rgb(214,86,43);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    padding: 10px;
   } 
   p { color: green; }
   div {
    background-color: hsl(60,100%,25%);
    color: hsla(120,100%,50%,0.1);
   } 
</style>
 </head>
</body>
</html> 
<h2>Статистика</h2>
<p><a href="?interval=1">За сегодня</a></p>
<p><a href="?interval=7">За последнюю неделю</a></p>
<p><a href="?interval=30">За послединий месяц</a></p>
<p><a href="?interval=183">За последнюю пол года</a></p>
<p><a href="?interval=365">За последний год</a></p>
<table style="border: 1px solid silver;">
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid silver;">Дата</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid silver;">Уникальных посетителей</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid silver;">Просмотров</td>
</tr>

<?php
// Если в массиве GET есть элемент interval (т.е. был клик по одной из ссылок выше)
if ($_GET['interval'])
{
 $interval = $_GET['interval'];
    
    // Если в качестве параметра передано не число
    if (!is_numeric ($interval))
    {
        echo '<p><b>Недопустимый параметр!</b></p>';        
    }
    
    // Указываем кодировку, в которой будет получена информация из базы 
    @mysqli_query ($db, 'set character_set_results = "utf8"');
    
    // Получаем из базы данные, отсортировав их по дате в обратном порядке в количестве interval штук
 $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `visits` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $interval");    
    
    // Формируем вывод строк таблицы в цикле
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
  echo '<tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid silver;">' . $row['date'] . '</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid silver;">' . $row['hosts'] . '</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid silver;">' . $row['views'] . '</td>
    </tr>';
 } 
}
?>
<div>.</div>
</table>
```

```html
<?php include 'db.php';

// Указываем кодировку, в которой будет получена информация из базы 
@mysqli_query ($db, 'set character_set_results = "utf8"');

// Получаем IP-адрес посетителя и сохраняем текущую дату 
$visitor_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");

// Узнаем, были ли посещения за сегодня   
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `visit_id` FROM `visits` WHERE `date`='$date'") or die ("Проблема при подключении к БД");

// Если сегодня еще не было посещений
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0)
{
    // Очищаем таблицу ips
    mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM `ips`");
    
    // Заносим в базу IP-адрес текущего посетителя
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `ips` SET `ip_address`='$visitor_ip'");
    
    // Заносим в базу дату посещения и устанавливаем кол-во просмотров и уник. посещений в значение 1
    $res_count = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `visits` SET `date`='$date', `hosts`=1,`views`=1");
}

// Если посещения сегодня уже были
else
{   
    // Проверяем, есть ли уже в базе IP-адрес, с которого происходит обращение
    $current_ip = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `ip_id` FROM `ips` WHERE `ip_address`='$visitor_ip'");
    
    // Если такой IP-адрес уже сегодня был (т.е. это не уникальный посетитель) 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($current_ip) == 1)
    {
        // Добавляем для текущей даты +1 просмотр (хит)
        mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `visits` SET `views`=`views`+1 WHERE `date`='$date'");
    }
    
    // Если сегодня такого IP-адреса еще не было (т.е. это уникальный посетитель)
    else
    {   
        // Заносим в базу IP-адрес этого посетителя
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `ips` SET `ip_address`='$visitor_ip'");
        
        // Добавляем в базу +1 уникального посетителя (хост) и +1 просмотр (хит)
        mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `visits` SET `hosts`=`hosts`+1,`views`=`views`+1 WHERE `date`='$date'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, Вам нужен запрос суммы всех просмотров за некоторый период (например за год). Это можно сделать так:

```
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(`views`) FROM `visits` WHERE `date` >= '2016-01-01' AND `date` <= '2017-01-01'");
```

Для вывода на страницу:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo $row['views'];
}
```

Comment: Вставил код таким образом , $result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(views) FROM visits WHERE date >= '2016-01-01' AND date <= '2017-01-31' ");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];.                                                                                          Вот что пишет (Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Y:\home\statistic\www\admin\index.php on line 64 ) Что я сделал не так?

Comment: И надо еще что бы суму выводило на экран ...

Comment: Ну для начала Вы не передали первый параметр в функцию  mysqli_query. Смотрите ответ. Я отредактировал его

Comment: Вставил (<?php 
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(`views`) FROM `visits` WHERE `date` >= '2016-01-01' AND `date` <= '2017-01-01'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo $row['views'];
}
 ?>) . Теперь на сайте не вылетает ошибки но и ничего не происходит ...И как передавать первый параметр?

Comment: $row['views'] - Содержит сумму просмотров за год. Просто выведите его там где Вам нужно на странице.

Comment: Это я понял , я вроде вел . Вот вообщем в коде как я вел (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e1OQ.png)а вот как оно выглядит на форме ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/8711W.png . Извините за то что я такой тупой ( Но что не так ?

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста (